# "AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'coroutine'." in Python 3.11.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, python-decorators

When I ran the code below with **`@asyncio.coroutine` decorator** on **Python 3.11.0**:

```py
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine # Here
def test():
    print("Test")

asyncio.run(test())
```

I got the error below:

> AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'coroutine'. Did you mean: 'coroutines'?

I find **`@asyncio.coroutine` decorator** is used for some code as far as I googled.

So, how can I solve this error?

Answer (score 12):

[**Generator-based Coroutines**](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/asyncio-task.html#generator-based-coroutines) which contains **`@asyncio.coroutine` decorator** is removed since **Python 3.11** so **`asyncio` module** doesn't have **`@asyncio.coroutine` decorator** as the error says:

> Note: Support for generator-based coroutines is deprecated and is removed in Python 3.11.

So instead, you need to use **`async` keyword** before `def` as shown below:

```py
import asyncio

# Here
async def test():
    print("Test")

asyncio.run(test()) # Test
```

Then, you can solve the error:

```
Test
```