# Asyncio has no attribute coroutine?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Hello this is my first time using API's and Asyncio. I am trying to write a simple script using the siege API import on python. However upon running the program I am hit with this error. I have read other questions with this error but don't think they apply to me or I am misunderstanding something.

```
import asyncio
import r6sapi as api

async def run():
    auth = api.Auth("email", "password")
    
    player = await auth.get_player("PLAYER_NAME", api.Platforms.UPLAY)
    operator = await player.get_operator("sledge")
    print(operator.kills)

    await auth.close()
    
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(run())
```

The Error Code is as follows:

> AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'coroutine'. Did you mean: 'coroutines'?

I tried to define asyncio.coroutines but then I can't use the await function. If anyone has any ideas fire away. Acording to python documentation you're not supposed to define asyncio.corountines anyway so I'm not really sure where to go from here. As another note is it because it is a generator based coroutine and my version of python is too new?

In case needed here is the entire traceroute:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\cincy\OneDrive\Documents\PythonSiegeAPI\r6api.py", line 2, in <module>
    import r6sapi as api
  File "C:\Users\cincy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\r6sapi\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .auth import *
  File "C:\Users\cincy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\r6sapi\auth.py", line 11, in <module>
    import aiohttp
  File "C:\Users\cincy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .client import *  # noqa
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\cincy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 15, in <module>
    from . import connector as connector_mod
  File "C:\Users\cincy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import hdrs, helpers
  File "C:\Users\cincy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\helpers.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .abc import AbstractAccessLogger
  File "C:\Users\cincy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\abc.py", line 10, in <module>
    class AbstractRouter(ABC):
  File "C:\Users\cincy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\abc.py", line 31, in AbstractRouter
    @asyncio.coroutine  # pragma: no branch
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the entire traceback. It is not clear *what* is actually triggering the error otherwise.

Comment: Are you using `@coroutine` decorator in any of the functions you're calling?

Comment: I have included the entire traceroute @MisterMiyagi

Comment: from what I'm aware of no @Jeppe

Comment: Looks like the [`r6sapi` auth](https://github.com/billy-yoyo/RainbowSixSiege-Python-API/blob/master/r6sapi/auth.py) does. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74345065/attributeerror-module-asyncio-has-no-attribute-coroutine-in-python-3-11

Comment: `r6sapi` is unmaintained for years. It does not run on any Python version newer than Python 3.10.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I will close this down as I did not realize. Should just require a few updates to the Auth code though.